# Which source says the Prophet left behind the Quran and Sunnah in his last sermon?

Tags: hadith, sunnah, source-identification

I have read that in his last sermon, Muhammad (PBUH) mentioned the Quran and Sunnah.

> I leave behind me two things, the Qur'an and my example, the Sunnah
>   and if you follow these you will never go astray.
>   ([alim.org](http://www.alim.org/library/hadith/prophet))

But some people dispute it and say Sahih Sitta books contain hadiths about the **Quran and his Family**.

> ألا أيها الناس فإنما أنا بشر يوشك أن يأتي رسول ربي فأجيب، وأنا تارك فيكم ثقلين: أولهما كتاب الله فيه الهدى والنور فخذوا بكتاب الله، واستمسكوا به فحث على كتاب الله ورغب فيه، ثم قال: و**أهل بيتي** أذكركم الله في أهل بيتي، أذكركم الله في أهل بيتي، أذكركم الله في أهل بيتي
>
> "O people, I am only human, and soon the messenger of my Lord will come
>   to me and I will respond. I am leaving among you two weighty
>   things, the first of which is the Book of Allah in which is
>   guidance and light. Follow the Book of Allah and hold fast to it." And he encouraged us to adhere to the Book of Allah, then he said: "And **the people of
>   my household**, I remind you of Allah with regard to the people of my household, I remind you of Allah with regard to the people of my household, I remind you of
>   Allah with regard to the people of my household."
>
> <sup>— **[Sahih Muslim, كتاب فضائل الصحابة - باب من فضائل علي بن أبي طالب رضي الله عنه](https://archive.org/stream/SahihMuslimarabic-English7VolumesPublishedByDarussalam/SahihMuslimVol.6-ahadith5646-6722#page/n267/mode/2up)** - ([sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/muslim/44/55))</sup>

Can we find the hadith which supports the view point of Quran and Sunnah?

Answer (score 3):

The Prophet ﷺ delivered at least three sermons on his farewell pilgrimage: on the day of Day of 'Arafah, on the day of Nahr and in middle of the days of Tashriq.

The hadith which mentions him leaving behind the Quran and Sunnah on this occasion is as follows:

> #### عن ابن عباس، رضي الله عنهما أن رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم خطب الناس في حجة الوداع فقال: يا أيها الناس إني قد تركت فيكم ما إن اعتصمتم به فلن تضلوا أبدا كتاب الله وسنة نبيه
>
> Narrated Ibn Abbas that the Messenger of Allah ﷺ addressed the people on the farewell Hajj and said: "*O People! I am leaving among you such a thing that if you strongly adhere to it you will never go astray, the Book of Allah and the Sunnah of the Prophet.*"
>
> <sup>—  [Mustadrak al-Hakim](https://shamela.ws/book/2266/304) and [Sunan Kubra al-Bayhaqi](https://shamela.ws/book/7861/23097)</sup>

Analogous ahadith are also recorded in [Muwatta Malik](https://sunnah.com/urn/516070) , [Sunan al-Daraqutni](https://shamela.ws/book/9771/4318#p1) and others.

Note that reliance on the Sunnah is also proven by stronger evidence from the Quran itself, from several other ahadith, from Ijma' and from reason.

Comment: Does this invalidate the other narrations from Sahih books which mention *The second are the members of my household* ? Or they're not conflicting?

Comment: @Honey Obviously it does not invalidate the hadith of Sahih Muslim, and neither is there a conflict. Adhering to the Quran is already inclusive of adhering to the Sunnah as the Quran commands it. The hadith of Muslim enjoins good treatment and respect towards the Ahlul Bayt. And we seek knowledge of the Sunnah and religious understanding from all of the Ahlul Bayt, including the wives of the Prophet and all of the Bani Hashim, the line of Abi Talib, Abbas and Harith.

Comment: Minor correction. Based on [Sahih Muslim - Book pertaining to the merits of the companions](http://www.iium.edu.my/deed/hadith/muslim/031_smt.html#017_b31) the wives are excluded: _Aren't his wives the members of his family? Thereupon he said: His wives are the members of his family (but here) the members of his family are those for whom acceptance of Zakat is forbidden._ Also it's not good treatment, it's much more _adhere to it....He exhorted (us) (to hold fast) to the Book of Allah...The second are the members of my household_ [just as how you adhere to Quran]

Comment: @Honey There is difference of opinion on that, there is a view that the wives of the Prophet ﷺ are included in the Ahlul Bayt based on e.g. [11:73](https://quran.com/11/73), [33:33](https://quran.com/33/33)  etc.

Comment: Secondly the wording of the Hadith of Sahih Muslim is only وأهل بيتي أذكركم الله في أهل بيتي أذكركم الله في أهل بيتي أذكركم الله في أهل بيتي . What you are suggesting about adhering to them *just like* the Quran, is more of an assumption rather than literally apparent, as one thing has been said about the Quran alone and then the Ahlul Bayt are mentioned separately after the first discourse is completed. At any rate this discussion is tangential to the topic at hand, as the question has only asked about the source of the hadith.

Answer (score 0):

There's a strong evidence that following Sunnah (and Sunnah of Prophet) means following the household (Ahlul Bait) of Prophet Muhammad (pbuh)!

...I leave behind the Two Weighty things. The first of them is the Book of Allah wherein there is light and guidance. Whoever holds firm on to it will be on certain guidance and whoever lets go or leaves it will be led astray. Also, my family (Ahlul Bait), I remind you to fear (of your duties) Allah with regards to my family. Hold firm to the rope of Allah and do not become disunited (do not go astray).

Allah's Messenger (saw) stood up to deliver sermon at a watering place known as Khumm situated between Mecca and Medina. He praised Allah, extolled Him and delivered the sermon and exhorted (us) and said: Now to our purpose. O people, I am a human being. I am about to receive a messenger (the angel of death) from my Lord and I, in response to Allah's call, (would bid good-bye to you), but I am leaving among you two weighty things: the one being the Book of Allah in which there is right guidance and light, so hold fast (do not go astray) to the Book of Allah and adhere to it and then said: The second are the members of my household (Ahlul Bait) I remind you (of your duties) to the members of my family. I remind you, I remind you! They will not dissent until they return to me at the Fountain, so look at how you treat them after me.

References:
Sahih Muslim 2408, 5920, 5923, 6225
Tirmidhi v.6, Hadith 3788
Riyad as-Salihin 712, In-book Hadith 32